# Доступ к страннице только по ссылке

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Как обеспечить доступ к странице только по ссылке переданной администратором? 
Извиняюсь что сразу не обрисовал вопрос четко. Исправлясь.
Задача состоит в том, что бы сделать регистрацию пользователя не общедоступной, а только по ссылке которую передает ADMIN.
Для начала не очень понимаю, какой метод отвечает за доступ к странице по ссылке
Есть такой код

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/index").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole(ADMIN)
```

Так же есть страница админа с кнопочкой для создания нового юзера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUser(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "addUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "addUser";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что сразу не обрисовал вопрос четко. Исправлясь.

Answer (score 1):

Кода не вижу, поэтому опишу в общих чертах. Админ генерирует ссылку, она пишется в БД. Разграничиваем права доступа к странице и запрещаем доступ кроме тех, кто перешел по конкретной ссылке. Для проверки смотрим в БД есть ли такая ссылка и когда она была сгенерирована (можно еще прописать и время жизни). Если есть - пускаем, нет - выбиваем 404

Comment: "Разграничиваем права доступа к странице и запрещаем доступ кроме тех, кто перешел по конкретной ссылке." 
Вот это я как раз и не знаю как сделать

Comment: в бд каждому юзеру выделяем поля is_verified и url. Если url из БД был выдан юзеру, то is_verified делаем true и далее при входе на страницу проводим валидацию по этому полю. Это костыль, но должно работать